# Use models outside a view

Tags: django, import

To send emails and stuff, I use code outside the views.py file (too much code there). I created a file named "tools.py" in the app folder where I start with

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from mysite.myapp.models import MyModel
```

With runserver, I have an error `ImportError: cannot import name MyModel`

This is strange as I use the same import in the views.py file and there is no problem...

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have a circular import. Are you importing this tools.py file in your myapp/models.py?

Comment: Yes I do. I use a function defined in tools in a model, I guess I shouldn't have.

Comment: Generally, circular imports indicate a design flaw. If tools needs models and models needs tools, then it should really be all part of the same module. So, yes, you should probably move relevant items into  myapp/models.py.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- Make sure you have your  **init**.py file in the folder where your
  "tools.py" file is located, this is a common reason why something might not be found.

I'm working on setting up something that requires something very similar to your requirements.

If you are trying to have this as a on/off process eg.) cronjob, worker etc. Do the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
######################################################################### 
# Required DO NOT REMOVE
#########################################################################
import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "appname.settings")
#########################################################################

# Import My Models, or Run an Include to Handle Processing.
from app.models.model import *

# Do Stuff to Test ( I suggest a simple insert into the model or pull and return content )
```

Save this file in the same folder that your "manage.py" is saved in, you can call this directly and it should process, you can setup a cronjob for it to run, etc. This allows you
to have a little less code as it doesn't run some of the processes that django runs prior to rendering a view from the urls.py file.

If this is unclear please feel free to comment and I will edit with correction or further details.

All the best